# GGTS - No Grails installation configured in the workspace preferences

Tags: eclipse, grails, ggts

I just installed Groovy/Grails Tool Suite on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I went to create a new Grails project and I get this error.

```
No Grails installation configured
```

or

```
No Grails installation configured in the workspace preferences.
```

depending on whether I have started typing a name for the project.

[image]

How do I configure grails?

Comment: Grails 3.0? Not sure that's supported in GGTS

Comment: GRAILS_HOME tells me that I am running Grails Version: 3.1.12, Groovy Version: 2.4.7, JVM Version: 1.8.0_101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to configure it? (if you find out that GGTS do not see Grails 3.x than try to install current elipse and add grails/groovy plugins manually)
[image]